# Laravel 8/Mailchimp: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl-certificate, wamp, mailchimp

**Problem**

Following [Laracasts tutorial for Laravel 8](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) (and to be specific: [Chapter 58 - Mailchimp API Tinkering, Section 11 - Newsletters and APIs](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/58)), I ran into an issue which seemed to be pretty common.

After creating a Mailchimp account and using a newly generated API key in Laravel 8, you would test it by [Making your first API call](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/quick-start/#make-your-first-api-call), through your `web.php` file:

```
Route::get('ping', function (){
    $mailchimp = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();

    $mailchimp->setConfig([
        'apiKey' => config('services.mailchimp.key'),
        'server' => 'us19'
    ]);

    $response = $mailchimp->ping->get();
    ddd($response);
});
```

Unfortunately, when dumping the `$response`, the following error would show up:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) 
for https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ping
```

**My Stack**

I'm using Laravel 8.79.0 and WampServer 3.2.6
(with Apache 2.4.51, MySQL 8.0.27, PHP 8.0.13, PHPMyAdmin 5.1.1).

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

To solve this error, I first downloaded the [cacert.pem certificate](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).

I placed it into a directory in my Wamp installation (in my case, I placed it in: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.13\extras\ssl).

Next, in the `php.ini` file of my PHP installation (in Wamp you can find it by left clicking the icon->PHP->php.ini), I looked for `curl.cainfo =`  which was commented out with a `;`.

I un-commented that line and set the value equal the absolute path to the `cacert.pem` file, so in my case the line was now: `curl.cainfo = C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.13\extras\ssl\cacert.pem`.

Finally, I Restarted All Services in WampServer and visited the page again. The API responded nicely with:

```
{#804 ▼
   +"health_status": "Everything's Chimpy!"
}
```

:)